# how to parse data from multiple json fields and combine them in one list?

Tags: python, json, parsing

Lets assume I have 3 fields per object in a json file. They are

```
[{
    "morning" :   "[0, 1, 4, 6]",
    "afternoon" : "[0, 2, 3, 5, 6]",
    "evening" :   "[1, 4, 6]"
},
    .
    .
    .
{
    "morning" :   "[3, 5, 6]",
    "afternoon" : "[0, 2, 6]",
    "evening" :   "[1, 4, 6]"
}]
```

> Here,
>   0 = sunday, 1 = monday, . . . . 6 = saturday

.
I want to parse the json file in such a way, where instead of 3 fields (morning, afternoon, evening) I will have only 1 field named schedule which is a list of 21 elements. Because I have 3 times in a day and 7 days in a week. which gives me the number 21.

I want the end result to be like this,

> "schedule" : "[sm, sa, se, mm, ma, me, tm, ta, te, wm, wa, we, thm, tha, the, fm, fa, fe, sam, saa, sae]"
>
> here sm = sunday_morning, ma = monday_afternoon, the = thursday_evening

OUTPUT EXAMPLE FOR 1ST OBJ:

```
"schedule" : [true, true, false, true, false, false, false, true, false, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, true, true]
```

Comment: What did you try and what went wrong ?

Comment: Is there any reason, why the lists are `strings` (`"[3, 5, 6]"`) ?

Comment: I am trying to think the algorithm.
what I did is define a list of 21 elements and pass morning, afternoon, evening list in  a function.
that function insert true or false based on data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over each day (in this case 7 days) and then check if the current day is present in the mentioned arrays (morning, afternoon and evening) or not. If it is present, you can append `true` in a list variable, or else `false`.

You will have to check for each condition, i.e. morning, afternoon and evening to append the availability for each day.

As requested, to successfully parse, Null (empty/None) values in your JSON Data, You need to first check whether the field is empty or not. If it is empty, simply append false and continue for next condition, each for the three timings (morning, afternoon and evening).

As per your requirement, here is a sample code which may help:

```
import json

# Sample JSON Input
input = '{"morning":[],"afternoon":null,"evening":"[1, 4, 6]"}'

jsonInput = json.loads(input)

# Start processing
schedule = []

for x in range(0, 7):

    if jsonInput['morning'] is None:
        schedule.append('false')
    else:
        if str(x) in jsonInput['morning']:
            schedule.append('true')
        else:
            schedule.append('false')
    if jsonInput['afternoon'] is None:
        schedule.append('false')
    else:
        if str(x) in jsonInput['afternoon']:
            schedule.append('true')
        else:
            schedule.append('false')
    if jsonInput['evening'] is None:
        schedule.append('false')
    else:
        if str(x) in jsonInput['evening']:
            schedule.append('true')
        else:
            schedule.append('false')

print(jsonInput)
print(schedule)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and showing me how to solve this problem LIVE.

Comment: facing a little more problem. How to deal with if the value for morning, afternoon or evening is null ??
In that case I want to append false in the specific slots

Comment: null will be represented by an empty array or null keyword?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check if this is what you wanted.